# How to install flash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, flash, pepperflash

I am trying to install a flash player in Ubuntu. I followed the below link:

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-adobe-flash-player-linux-terminal/

- I enabled Enable Canonical Repository
- Update the system
- While using the command `apt install adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` I am getting `unable to locate package browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

Can anyone leave their suggestions here, it would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

`browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` is in multiverse, so open the *Software & Updates* tool and enable multiverse there.

With that said, you may want to study the Flash page in Ubuntu's official desktop documentation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: Thank you Gunnar, your suggestion solved my problem. Much appreciated. :-)